# How to validate the contents inside the JSON body

Tags: json, validation, post, postman

In postman i want to to validate  '"name": "Twilio"', which is inside data > twilio > viewable > name

here is the JSON response ive got

{
    "success": true,
    "timestamp": "2019-08-12T12:31:33+00:00",
    "response_code": 200,
    "data": {
        "twilio": {
            "name": "Twilio",
            "slug": "twilio",
            "image": "https://s3-eu-west-1.amazonaws.com/connector-assets/images/twilio.png",
            "description": "Twilio is a cloud communications platform as a service. Integrate your Twilio account to send outgoing SMS from Purple.",
            "category": "communication",
            "connectedCount": 1,
            "allowMultipleAdd": false,
            "editable": [],
            "viewable": {
                "cf-5d51503868af3": {
                    "name": "Twilio"
                }
            },
            "id": "cf-5d515c2527579",
            "overrideAllowed": false
        },
        "salesforce-mc": {
            "name": "Salesforce marketing cloud",
            "slug": "salesforce-mc",
            "image": "https://s3-eu-west-1.amazonaws.com/connector-assets/images/sf-mc.png",
            "description": "Salesforce Marketing Cloud is a provider of digital marketing automation and analytics software and services.",
            "category": "marketing-automation",
            "connectedCount": 0,
            "allowMultipleAdd": true,
            "editable": [],
            "viewable": [],
            "id": "cf-5d515c252bc31",
            "overrideAllowed": true
        }
    }
}

Comment: Do the validation on server side code.

Answer (score -2):

The easiest way is to process the response as JSON, and simply check your hierarchy:

In the tests section, you can add a number of tests:

```
pm.test("Response should be OK", function () { 
    pm.response.to.be.ok;
});

// You can actually check for explicit response code if a 200 series is not enough.
pm.test("Status code is 200", function () {
    pm.response.to.have.status(200);
});

// Optionally test the returned Content-Type is correct.
pm.test("Content-Type is present", function () {
    pm.response.to.have.header("Content-Type");
});

pm.test("Response should be okay to process", function () { 
    pm.response.to.be.ok;
    pm.response.to.not.be.error; 
});

pm.test("Body contains JSON data result with Twilio as the viewable name", function () {
    const JsonData = pm.response.json();
    pm.expect(JsonData.data.twilio.viewable.name).to.equal('Twilio');
});
```

For safety, you can check that each parent element exists first (validate data is in JsonData) to avoid errors should the payload change or not match what you expect.

EDIT: Your JSON structure:

```
{ 
    "success": true, 
    "timestamp": "2019-08-12T12:31:33+00:00", 
    "response_code": 200, 
    "data": { 
        "twilio": { 
            "name": "Twilio", 
            "slug": "twilio", 
            "image": "https://s3-eu-west-1.amazonaws.com/connector-assets/images/twilio.png", 
            "description": "Twilio is a cloud communications platform as a service. Integrate your Twilio account to send outgoing SMS from Purple.", 
            "category": "communication", 
            "connectedCount": 1, 
            "allowMultipleAdd": false, 
            "editable": [], 
            "viewable": { 
                "cf-5d51503868af3": { 
                    "name": "Twilio" 
                }
            }, 
            "id": "cf-5d515c2527579", 
            "overrideAllowed": false 
        }, 
        "salesforce-mc": { 
            "name": "Salesforce marketing cloud", 
            "slug": "salesforce-mc", 
            "image": "https://s3-eu-west-1.amazonaws.com/connector-assets/images/sf-mc.png", 
            "description": "Salesforce Marketing Cloud is a provider of digital marketing automation and analytics software and services.", 
            "category": "marketing-automation", 
            "connectedCount": 0, 
            "allowMultipleAdd": true, 
            "editable": [], 
            "viewable": [], 
            "id": "cf-5d515c252bc31", 
            "overrideAllowed": true 
        }
    } 
}
```

Based on this, the text you are looking for is present, but under an ID, not directly available as you indicated.  There are two checks that could be done:
1. Use the name in the main block

```
pm.test("Body contains JSON data result with Twilio as the viewable name", function () {
    const JsonData = pm.response.json();
    pm.expect(JsonData.data.twilio.name).to.equal('Twilio');
});
```

2. The other would be to extract the viewable value ('cf-5d51503868af3') and use this value as a key to do the test.  Not sure if this is available to you from your user id or another data source.  If not, then you need to extract it from the `JsonData.data.twilio.viwable` object.  There are some more useful examples [here in this answer.](https://stackoverflow.com/a/56021573/755666)

Comment: 'code' pm.test("Body contains JSON data result with Twilio as the viewable name", function () {
    const JsonData = pm.response.json();
    pm.expect(JsonData.data.twilio.viewable.name).to.equal('Twilio');
}); 'code'
 
this didn't work for me

Comment: @MohammedAli Not sure what 'code' means? I have updated my answer with your JSON structure to help clarify.